# Ajax data to nicedit textarea

Tags: jquery, ajax, nicedit

I am using nicedit plugin in php file and it is working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    new nicEditor({buttonList : ['fontSize','bold','italic','underline','ol','ul','strikeThrough','subscript','superscript','forecolor','bgcolor']}).panelInstance('area4');
    nicEditors.findEditor('area4').saveContent();

    });
</script>
```

I want to put some value in nicedit editor from database by ajax.
Here is the ajax code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#autofill").change(function() {
            var data1= $('option:selected', this).text();
                            $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url:"autofill.php",
                        cache: false,
                        data: 'action1=' + data1,
                        beforeSend: function() { 
                            $("#validation-errors").hide().empty(); 
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(data.success == true)
                                {
                                   data = JSON.parse( data );
                                   $('#area4').val(data.title);
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#features-left-image").offset().top}, 2000);
                                }
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                            alert('Something went to wrong.Please Try again later...');
                            btn.button('reset');
                            alert(thrownError);
                        }
                    });             
                    return false;
                });

        });
    </script>
```

I checked and found json data is returning from **autofill.php** but for some reason i am not able to show them in nicedit editor. If i use textbox instead of nicedit then data is showing there but it is not working for nicedit textarea.

Have you ever face similar issue?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: [nicInstance].setContent(HTML) Set the current HTML in the editor instance. Read the manual. http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API

Comment: thanks for your comment. I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it working. Here is the code.

```
var ed=data.title;
nicEditors.findEditor('area4').setContent(ed);
```